# Can someone spot what's wrong with this code please?

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

```
SELECT  
  station_id,
  name
  FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations`
WHERE station_id IN (
  SELECT
    CAST(start_station_id AS STRING)
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` AS citibike_stations 
  WHERE
    usertype = 'Subscriber'   
)
```

I ran this code and it keeps saying 'no data found', I'm so confused why - I am not sure what is wrong with this code?

Comment: You should run the second alone and check the ids directly against the first. you will probably have no match

Comment: Please change the question title as something significant, for example "Bigquery cannot find data using subquery".

Answer (score 1):

From quick glance  - it looks like those station_id are totally different in those tables - so try below instead

```
SELECT  
  station_id,
  name
  FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations`
WHERE name IN (
  SELECT
    DISTINCT start_station_name
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` AS citibike_stations 
  WHERE
    usertype = 'Subscriber'   
)
```